# configurable product not allowing add to cart with only custom option selected

Tags: cart, custom, products, configurable-product, custom-options

This is driving me crazy! All the products on my site are configurable products they all have 1 or more associated simple products attached to them they all also have a custom option check-box.

My issue is that my system will not allow add to cart when only the product option is selected it keeps saying please select from the associated products.

How do I make my system so that it will allow add the product to the cart with only the custom option selected?

I really appreciate any help with this issue I am going round in circles.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what your problem is.

In magento a configurable product represents a group of simple products. When you add a configurable to your cart, in reality you are adding a simple product to your cart with another label.

When you omit the choice of the attribute, the system don't know what to add to the cart, so do I.

What is the intended behavior when you don't choose any option?

Comment: I have a fabric website that offers a product and the customer has an option of choosing the color, now I created a custom option on each product called "sample " with a check-box I would like the customer to be able to just add the config product to the cart as a sample when the check box is marked. does that make sense?

Comment: Basically instead of choosing a color the customer could just check mark the box add the product to the cart as a sample

Comment: here is the link

Comment: http://homefabricsandtrims.com/window-panels-1/merano-drapery.html   instead of selecting a color just check mark the box and add to cart (the cart would then show sample in the of (whatever product it was))

Comment: What does the customer get, when he orders a sample? If it is ONE color: create a second attribute for "sample", add a hidden field with the value of "not" and a checkbox for yes, then you have a configurable with two attributes and everything is fine. If he get all the colors, maybe you better add a link for the samples, then, with the link add sample product to the cart: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/catalog/adding_a_product_to_the_cart_via_querystring If you have different samples, put them into an attribute maybe?

Comment: It is just 1 sample of the product in question

Comment: do you have any more links to how would achieve your solution? would that also show the name of the sample in the cart and obviously the admin order?

Comment: What you can do is (how is described in the link), create a new (simple) product and this product is added to the cart, so you can do whatever you want with this simple product. You see the name in the cart, you can change the quantity (if not forbidden in backend), you can show an image, set a price, tax, etc. and the same applies of course for the backend :-)